# jQuery filtering or search a product catalog

Tags: jquery, search, filtering, catalog

Is there a jQuery plugin for filtering records in the same way as a webshop is filtering its products?

Choose some attributes and see the list beeing updated.

It is only aprox. 250 products to it is possible to show all and add attributes to the class for easy filtering.

So the plugin is more to create the form and maybe some extra features like counting how many is left if an attribute is checked...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.  :-)  But building one would be pretty easy.  Generate a multi-select HTML element with values being the DOM css classes to include/remove, and just use jQuery selectors to count/show/hide the results.  When the change event of the multiselect is triggered, collect all the values selected, create a selector by glomming those values together like `var sel = '.class1, .class2, .class3'` and then just do `$(sel).length` to count them, or `$(sel).hide()` to hide those that match, etc.

Comment: ok. Thanks for the unfortunate answer. Great you could point me in the right direction with the counting etc.